# How to send mail through spring API to BCC/CC if To E-mail address fails

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

I am using below Jars to send mails:

- spring-context-support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- mail-1.4.jar

& below API:

- JavaMailSender
- MimeMessageHelper

I am configuring TO,CC & BCC emails to send mails. I want to send mails to **CC/BCC list** even if **To email address** is invalid or fails to send.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do it through the Spring API, but JavaMail supports a "mail.smtp.sendpartial" property that causes it to send the message even if some of the addresses are invalid.